# Import specific range of Google spreadsheet

Tags: import, spreadsheets

I am trying to import only a specific range of a Google spreadsheet as data in Mathematica for further usage like plotting. So I tried to use the
 data = **Import**["https://...", "Data"] function, but get as a result everything in the spreadsheet, including the impressum. In the documentation I found the article about "Import a spreadsheet" for .xls, but when I try to specify the range via
 data = **Import**["https://..." ,{"Data", 1, Table[i, {i, 3, 12}], {1, 2, 3}}]
I get the error message "Import: The import element "3" is not present when importing as HTML."
So is it possible to import only some columns and rows out of my Google spreadsheet or do I have to download it as .xls?

Comment: Can you provide a working URL for sample data for others to explore this problem?

Comment: Yes of course, so from this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RHCJZGJ58EmDAVQgepODBPgfMW-5WfzcJOSa9Gn_bDE/edit?usp=sharing I want to import the second column and the third column in the rows 1 to 10

Comment: Is it useful to you to read the CSV file without *manually* downloading it, like this? `Import["https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RHCJZGJ58EmDAVQgepODBPgfMW-\
5WfzcJOSa9Gn_bDE/export?format=csv&id=1RHCJZGJ58EmDAVQgepODBPgfMW-5WfzcJOSa9Gn_bDE&\
gid=0", {"Data", Range[3, 9], {1, 2, 3}}]`

Comment: Yes, I just don't want to download every sheet every time manually, when me or other persons are updating the table. But actually when I copy this in my notebook (without the backslashes and gaps), I get the same error message as before: "The Import element "3" is not present when importing as HTML", even if the export format should be CSV?

Comment: It looks like the CSV link in my comment above expired.  Please try this attempt that does not require CSV export: `Import["https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RHCJZGJ58EmDAVQgepODBPgfMW-\
5WfzcJOSa9Gn_bDE/edit#gid=0", {"HTML", "Data", 1, 2, Range[3, 9], Range[2, 5]}]` – For me this gives output `{{"1,9", "0,701", "11,53", "0,005"}, {"2,6", "0,722", "17,86", "0,005"}, {3, 
  "0,732", "21,90", "0,005"}, {"3,3", "0,739", "25,32", "0,005"}, {4, "0,751", 
  "32,60", "0,005"}, {"4,7", "0,760", "38,30", "0,005"}, {"5,4", "0,768", "45,10", 
  "0,005"}}`

Comment: I get the same output now, thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for this helpful discussion... But how to Import a second tab in the spreadsheet? When importing an xls file I just Import["file.xls"][[2]], for the second tab, but how to do this for a google sheet?